# Winforms MDI Navigation Bar

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have searched and searched and searched, and all I can find is how to do this with RadControls, or with DevX controls.

How can I hide the minimize/close/maximize nav bar once my MDI Parent has loaded it's child form?

I've disabled them on the child form, I've changed borders, I've made sure to force the parent to be the MDIContainer, etc...  still they show!   I don't want them, nor need them there (in case you ask why)

Comment: "I don't want them, nor need them there (in case you ask why)"  Then don't use an MdiContainer!  Show your forms directly in a container (like a Panel?) by first setting TopLevel() to False, then adding them to a Controls() collection before calling Show().  This can only be done at run-time...

Comment: you mean to tell me that there is `no` way to hide that nav bar?   Then why is it possible with the DevX and RadControls?  I've also had 3rd party .net apps installed (no code of course), that were MDI Containers, without them

Comment: "Then why is it possible with the DevX and RadControls?"  Because they are written from **scratch** and are not using the stock .Net MdiContainer?...

Comment: Some years later: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50077382/4367

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WinForms, you don't.

If you want to use a border style of none, you are better off not using MDI at all, and just change your forms into UserControls by changing the TopLevel property to false and then dock filling the form into a panel on the parent form.

Comment: you mean to tell me that there is `no` way to hide that nav bar?   Then why is it possible with the DevX and RadControls?  I've also had 3rd party .net apps installed (no code of course), that were MDI Containers, without them

Comment: @o7thWebDesign Microsoft basically got MDI in a good enough working state and moved on to other things.  I don't have a stronger answer than that.

Comment: what about moving the app into WPF, and doing the same thing in a Frame with a Page loaded into it?   I see something about NavigationUI

Comment: @o7thWebDesign You can do a lot of things in WPF, but MDI isn't baked into that frame work.  It's not clear what navigation abilities you are looking for.

Comment: i just want to be able to load forms into a container window.  i think WPF might be the way to go with this.