# Remove top bar on child form

Tags: c#

Making an MDI form, i wish to remove the top bar on all child forms. Working on Visual studio and c#. Any idea how? Im clueless.

[image]

Here the properies of the child form:

```
Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
Me.MinimizeBox = False
Me.MaximizeBox = False
Me.ControlBox = False
Me.ShowIcon = False
Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
Me.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In order to effectively help you, we need to reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vb.net mdi child title bar not hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627295/vb-net-mdi-child-title-bar-not-hiding). This question is about VB.NET, but the same logic applies to C#.

Comment: Can you try to set ControlBox to false ?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed i've seen the post before posting, didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @AmineFellous Did you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25566118/4934172)? AFAICT, it works for both VB.NET and C#. If it _doesn't work_ for you, you need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50076948/edit) your question and explain _exactly_ what you have tried that _didn't work_.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed yes i tryed everything on that post, even opening the form with .show() method.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Option 1: <sup>*</sup>

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25566118/4934172), you can add a [MenuStrip control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/menustrip-control-windows-forms) to your MDI *parent* form, set its `Visible` property to false, and you should be good to go. The MDI child forms won't have a title bar displayed *as long as they are maximized*.

---

### Option 2: <sup>*</sup>

1. Set the `MdiParent` Property of the child form.
2. Set the `FormBorderStyle` property of the *child* form to `FormBorderStyle.None`.
3. Set the `Dock` property of the *child* form to `DockStyle.Fill`. *Note: This **must** come after setting the `MdiParent` or else it won't work*.
4. That's it, you don't need to change any other properties (`WindowState`, `ControlBox`, etc.). Just maintain the order of the steps above.

Here's an example:

```
private void OpenAndDockMdiChild()
{
    Form2 childForm = new Form2();
    childForm.MdiParent = this;              // This must come **before** setting 
                                             // the `Dock` property.
    childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    childForm.Show();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenAndDockMdiChild();
}
```

**Result:**

[image]
Hope that helps.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Tested with .NET 4.5.2 on both Windows 7 and Windows 10.</sub>

Comment: Thanx. Now it works by doing both. I changed the properties through the code, instead the form parameters.

Comment: @AmineFellous, Glad I was able to help. If there's still something not clear, please let me know.